# replacing LinkedList with Priorityqueue. the error showing is java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: java, priority-queue

[i have replaced the existing LinkedList with Priority queue which u can find in the image. and u can also find the error when i am running the loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3q3y.png)

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int sel;
    PriorityQueue<Worker> userQueue = new PriorityQueue<>();
    PriorityQueue<String> users = new PriorityQueue<>();
    while(true)
    {
        System.out.print("1) Add job\n2) Run Jobs\n3) Clear Jobs\n4) Add User\n5) Print users\n0) Exit\n");
        
        sel = getInteger(input);
        if (sel == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        else if (sel == 1)
        {
            System.out.print("1) Basic Job\n2) Repeating Job\n0) Cancel\n");
            sel = getInteger(input);
            if (sel == 1)
            {
                System.out.println("Enter job message");
                String msg = input.nextLine();
                msg = input.nextLine();
                userQueue.offer(new Worker(msg)); }
```

// i am getting exception at userQueue.offer(new Worker(msg)); //

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class cis265.Worker cannot be cast to class java.lang.Comparable (cis265.Worker is in module cis265_queue of loader 'app'; java.lang.Comparable is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at java.base/java.util.PriorityQueue.siftUpComparable(PriorityQueue.java:643)
    at java.base/java.util.PriorityQueue.siftUp(PriorityQueue.java:639)
    at java.base/java.util.PriorityQueue.offer(PriorityQueue.java:330)
    at cis265_queue/cis265.Cis265_queue.main(Cis265_queue.java:63)
```

Comment: Please show your code as text in the question, as a [mcve].

Comment: You also need to show the exception you get, and indicate the line in the code on which it occurs.

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental problem is that you're trying to put something into an order, without telling Java what that order should be.

See the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/PriorityQueue.html):

> A priority queue relying on natural ordering also does not permit insertion of non-comparable objects (doing so may result in `ClassCastException`).

So, either make your `Worker` implement `Comparable`, or provide a `Comparator` to the constructor of `PriorityQueue`.